# Function Parameters as Const Reference

Tags: c++

Is there any reason not to send a parameter as a `const &` , instead of by value, when it will not be changed and no copy will be made? My understanding is that a `const` by value parameter is the same as without the `const` (and won't overload each other) so it will still be copied.

I know it's best for large objects to send by `const &`, but I don't know where the line for this is. Or if even small parameters should be sent by value **if** they won't be changed or copied.

Note:: I tried searching for this but the topic is fairly vague so I did not find any good answers, I apologize if this has been answered already (found many questions about when to use `const` when to use `const &` but not about the advantages of value vs `const &` for objects not obviously large).

Comment: you might find this article interesting: http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

Comment: Exactly the type of thing I was looking for thanks! The keywords are so general it was hard for me to search.

Comment: @lccarrasco: Dave Abrahams is talking about returning objects by value from within functions. The question is about input parameters to functions. In this case the OP should pass objects other than native types by const reference.

Comment: Conceptually, a reference is an alias. It is _not a pointer_, although in some cases the compiler has no other choice but to secretly implement it as a pointer. Insofar it is true that sometimes passing primitive types by value may be as fast or faster. In many cases though, I've seen the compiler do truly amazing stuff with references, entirely eleminating them, basically as if you used the original variable in the other function's scope.

Comment: @iccarrasco's link is about the return value, indeed, but that's also an important thing to consider. Especially if you're wondering about the details of how arguments (and return values!) are passed during a function call, it's well worth knowing about RVO ... don't forget to compile with optimizations, too!

Comment: @Praetorian: Ah yes. The article is still interesting though.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's generally nothing wrong with passing read-only arguments as const-references, and for any sort of heavy-weight class that's surely the most efficient way to do it.

You might want to consider passing primitive types by copy, though, because there making the reference might actually incur *more* cost than just copying (e.g. copying would just fit into one register, while a reference might be implemented with a pointer, etc.).

Also, you can probably pass `std::shared_ptr` and iterators by value, they're made for that.

As for passing by const-value, that's an **implementation** detail. Use it like this:

```
// Declaration:
int foo(int n, double d); // No "const"! Constness is not part of the interface.

// Definition
int foo(int n, const double d) // implementation detail
{
  while (n--) { if (d > n) return n; }
}
```

In the implementation, you may or may not choose to use the argument variables directly and modify them (like `n`), or you may choose to treat them as read-only (like `d`), and you declare the arguments appropriately.

Comment: I did not think of the pointer copying being just as expensive or worse for primitive types, thanks.

Comment: Worthwhile to point out, if you pass a reference-counting handle (like `shared_ptr`) by reference across a thread boundary then it becomes **impossible to ever safely decrement the reference count** -- you *have* to pass by value in this case.

Answer (score 14):

As a rule of thumb, you should pass primitive types such as pointers, `int`, `bool`, `float`, `double` by (non-const) value, and object types such as `std::string`, `std::vector` and custom classes by (const) reference.  As an exception to this rule, there are light-weight classes that are specifically designed to be passed by value, such as smart pointers.

Passing a value by const value, e.g. `void foo(const double bar)`, makes no sense -- why shouldn't `foo` be allowed to modify its copy of `bar`?  Declaring the parameter as const has no use here.

Passing primitives by reference makes little sense as well.  Behind the scenes, when a parameter is passed by reference, a pointer is passed by value.  Copying a pointer is usually just as expensive as copying a primitive type (such as `int`), and parameters of type `const int&` look pretty weird to most C++ programmers.

Comment: There are some people (I am not among them) who actually prefer `const double bar`. They say it prevents bugs causes by overwriting the value of a parameter in a function.

Comment: Just to add to @larsmans' comment, using `const double bar` prevents you from accidentally doing `if (bar = 5)` instead of `==`. But that's at the cost of limiting what you can do with `bar`. Your algorithm might demand in-place modification of `bar` for some reason. I guess it's just a tradeoff of flexibility vs. safety. Depends how much you want to trust the next programmer!

Answer (score 3):

Unless an interface demands it, primitives **should** be passed by value.  Otherwise, const& is a better practice.

[boost::is_fundamental](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_fundamental.html)

[Identifying primitive types in templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580922/identifying-primitive-types-in-templates)