# Is there a way to specialize a template to target primitives?

Tags: c++, templates, primitive

In specializing a class template, I would like to have one specialization target full-blown classes (complete with constructor, destructor, etc.) and one specialization target primitives (`int`, `float`, etc.). The only partial specialization I've seen is with targeting pointer types (via `T*`). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is special about the full-blown classes that you want to specialize differently?  Do they have some special member that you need?

Comment: Well, for primitives, I can do a blanket `memcpy` for certain operations, whereas for classes, I need to invoke each copy operation individually.

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw: Then you don't want to specialize on primitive/classes, but rather on POD vs non-POD types

Comment: You probably want to specialize based on something like the type trait is_trivially_copyable

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: And in C++11, the decided factor is `is_standard_layout`. Standard layout classes can be treated as a sequence of bytes, POD being a subset of those.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can used C++11 [type_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types). Here is something to get you started, you can specialize more as needed:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename E = void>
struct A; // undefined

template<typename T>
struct A<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<T>::value && !std::is_pod<T>::value>::type> {
        A() { std::cout << "I'm a class, but I'm not a pod type" << std::endl; }
};

template<typename T>
struct A<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<T>::value && std::is_pod<T>::value>::type> {
        A() { std::cout << "I'm a class and a pod type" << std::endl; }
};

template<typename T>
struct A<T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_class<T>::value>::type> {
        A() { std::cout << "I'm not a class" << std::endl; }
};

class X {};
class Y { ~Y(){} };

int main()
{
        A<X> a1;
        A<Y> a2;
        A<int> a3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`boost::has_trivial_assign` should give you this info.

```
template <class T>
  struct has_trivial_assign : public true_type-or-false_type {};
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/has_trivial_assign.html

Comment: Classes can have trivial assignment operators, so this would give the OP false positives.