# How to condition a class template and primitive type template

Tags: c++

I am trying to build a class template that inherits the class. If the class template is given a primitive type as template argument, then it gives an illegal inheritance error. I tried doing

```
template <class Class_>
struct EndianGuard_ : public Class_ {
  EndianGuard_ () {
    cout << "Guarding a Class" << endl;
  }
}

template <typename PrimitiveType_>
struct EndianGuard_ {
  EndianGuard_ (PrimitiveType_ Value) : Value(Value) {
    cout << "Guarding a primitive type" << endl;
  }
  PrimitiveType_ Value;
}
```

of course I knew it doesn't work that way but I am desperate. How can I differentiate primitive type and a structure?

Comment: So you want to inherit only if Class_ is not a primitive type?

Comment: also wrap the primitive types

Comment: Do you mean if you use int, or double, for example, as the type for 'PrimativeType' it doesn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identifying primitive types in templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580922/identifying-primitive-types-in-templates) (which uses `std::is_fundamental`) or [Is there a way to specialize a template to target primitives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287043/is-there-a-way-to-specialize-a-template-to-target-primitives) (which uses its inverse, `std::is_class`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where a template specialization comes in handy.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class Class_, bool = std::is_class<Class_>::value>
struct EndianGuard_ : public Class_ 
{
    // inherit if class
};

template <class Class_>
struct EndianGuard_<Class_, false> 
{
    // don't inherit if not a class
};

struct foo {};

int main() 
{
    EndianGuard_<int> f; //ok
    EndianGuard_<foo> f2; // ok
}
```

If `std::is_class<Class_>::value` evaluates to `false`, the specialization kicks in and you can handle the non-class type. Other conditions can be added for more restriction.
As a side note, it's probably best to handle the `std::is_final` case, since you can't inherit from a `final` class.