# What does (struct PToMTraits<U V::*>) template specification mean?

Tags: c++, templates

I found this type trait in the Alexandrescu book and I have no idea how to understand this specification

```
template <typename T>
class TypeTraits
{
private:
template <class U> struct PToMTraits
{
enum { result = false };
};
template <class U, class V>
struct PToMTraits<U V::*>
{
enum { result = true };
};
public:
enum { isMemberPointer = PToMTraits<T>::result };
...
};
```

Comment: [this_link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580922/identifying-primitive-types-in-templates) might help you to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a **P**ointer **to** **M**ember checker, hence **PtoM**.

It checks to see if the type passed in is a pointer-to-data-member type (or not). It does this by providing a primary template whose `result` is `false` and a partial specialization on any type that matches `U V::*` (that is a pointer to a data member of any class `U` of any type `V`), whose `result` is `true`.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Could you explain why this "U V::*" stands for pointer to a data member of type V which belongs to U? This syntax doesn't look like C++ for me:)

Comment: @Scipio That's just what the syntax is.

Comment: Ok, I found a clarifying example here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters (At the bottom of page) and finally understood it.